# Git Incorrect SSH Key (Pushing to Heroku)

Tags: git, heroku, ssh

I have been trying to clone a project on Heroku.

I have already checked to see that my key (`id_rsa.pub`) has been added to Heroku via `heroku keys:add` and that it shows up correctly under `heroku keys:status`

However, when I do `git clone`, I get `Permission denied (public key)`. This leads me to believe that my ssh settings are incorrect. Note, I am working on a Ubuntu machine.

To debug this even further, I tried to clone a github repo. Which confirming my belief, worked when using https but not ssh (same error).

My question:

How do I determine which private key git is trying to use to perform the cloning operation.

Additionally, I have tried adding a `config` file to my `.ssh` folder with the contents:

```
Host heroku.com
Hostname heroku.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: Ubuntu should use `id_rsa` by default. Do the fingerprints match? Is `id_rsa` the only key you have in there, or do you also have an `id_dsa`?

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you are using an ssh config file, you should:

- not named it like the Hostname (Host `heroku`, for instance, is enough)
- add the User (`git`)

The idea behind a config spec is to:

- [manage multiple heroku accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4663103/6309),
- but also to have *shorter* ssh url.
  (Really no need to repeat `git@...` in front of each ssh url: the user is always '`git`' here).

Your config file should be:

```
Host heroku
Hostname heroku.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Your ssh url should then be:

```
ssh://heroku:appname.git
```