# Heroku: Your account example@email.com does not have access to <app-name>

Tags: git, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having trouble pushing code to Heroku. I have an account but I've forgotten the password. I created a new account and tried to push with it but now it shows me this error:

```
Your account someoneelse@gmail.com does not have access to
! SSH Key Fingerprint:
```

How can I log in with the new account? I'd like to remove this error message with a fresh account. I have uploaded my latest ssh key to heroku. I have tried everything to push code on heroku (basic setup), but I can't get past this error.

---

Any application in your account has two ssh key and you should remove one which is not in your "~/.ssh/" folder or follow these steps.

Here's the solution:

1. Go to [www.heroku.com](http://www.heroku.com) and login with the account that raises the error.
2. Go to the applications settings. (e.g. for an application named "rails-demo", go to rails-demo settings and check whether there are two ssh keys)
3. Remove the key which is no longer in your system
4. Or you can remove them both and then generate new one with these commands.

   `-> ssh-keygen -t rsa`

   `-> heroku keys:add`
5. Upload the new one and then in your console type

   `-> heroku log-in`
6. Log in with your account and then push it to you app.
7. It's solved now.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to:

- clean any extra ssh key in your Heroku app that you don't have locally (See [SSR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2279018/ssr)'s [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20586992/revisions))
- register your new account (as described in "[Managing Multiple Heroku Accounts](http://martyhaught.com/articles/2010/12/14/managing-multiple-heroku-accounts/)"):

  <del>`heroku accounts:add myNewAccount`</del> (2013, [`ddollar/heroku-accounts`](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts)deprecated)
   Use [`heroku/heroku-accounts`](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-accounts) with `heroku plugins:install heroku-accounts`
   `heroku accounts:add myNewAccount` followed by Heroku credentials (Email, password)

Make sure [your `~/.ssh/config` file has an '`myNewAccount`' entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8856271/6309)

```
Host heroku.myNewAccount
  HostName heroku.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_heroku_myNewAccount_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

And then **change the remote 'origin' url**:

```
git remote set-url origin git@heroku.myNewAccount:<appname>.git
```

Or, as [Ian Vaughan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119790/ian-vaughan) [comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586992/your-account-someoneelsegmail-com-does-not-have-access-to-app-name/20592890#comment36680179_20592890)

> `origin` is normally `heroku` when using the 'heroku-toolbelt':

```
git remote set-url heroku git@heroku.myNewAccount:<appname>.git
```

That last step will make sure the `git push` will use your new account, and not the old one.

See more at "[Multiple heroku accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4663103/6309)".

---

If you add "User git" in your config file, you can remove the credential user name '`git`':

```
Host heroku.myNewAccount
  User git
  HostName heroku.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_heroku_myNewAccount_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

That means you can use:

```
git remote set-url origin heroku.myNewAccount:<appname>.git
# or
git remote set-url heroku heroku.myNewAccount:<appname>.git
```

Comment: but i want to remove all the credentials. how to do that? still m getting the error.

Comment: @SSR I have edited the answer: you can remove the '`git@`' part of the url, but some kind of credential will have to be used when accessing to your remote url.

Comment: In my case, was necessary only the last step. When I create the account it got the appname wrong. Change it only the "origin" for "heroku" and the appname to my right appname.

Comment: As @CassioS.Cabral states, `origin` is normally `heroku` when using the heroku-toolbelt, not sure if the answer needs updating as `origin` is the norm, and people know what that means?!

Comment: @VonC I like the `or`, I didnt think of that.

Comment: @GreenAsJade yes,  ddollar/heroku-accounts is obsolete indeed. I have edited the answer to point to https://github.com/heroku/heroku-accounts.

Answer (score 23):

This worked for me:

```
$ heroku auth:logout
```

Then

```
$ heroku auth:login
```

Comment: +1 to share your solution. Yes this will destroy your current session so you can continue with another session after.

Comment: Knew it would be something simple.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this work for you. By using this gem you can manage multiple account
https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts

Comment: Ya you can do it with this but you should remove extra ssh keys from your heroku account app. see mine solution and @VonC's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remove ssh key from your "homedir/.ssh" and check whether from that ssh key would not be available there.

I solved using your question after update.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple accounts then login with the new or required one

```
$ heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: new@example.com
Password: 

$ heroku keys:add
```

generate keys if you have old one already in use for another heroku account.

Comment: Then what about old one? If I need to use old account then? This is just for heroku account authentication. This won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when deploying a Rails application to Heroku.

After logging in to the Heroku CLI using the command:

```
heroku login
```

and also creating the new app using the command:

```
heroku create
```

when I run the command git push `heroku main`, I get the error below:

```
remote: !       Your account name@mymail.com does not have access to stark-temple-39676.
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.heroku.com/stark-temple-39676.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I tried several solutions but none worked for me.

**Here's how I fixed it**:

First I ran the command git remote -v to see the list of remote, and I got this output:

```
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/stark-temple-39676.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/stark-temple-39676.git (push)
```

The issue was that the name of the heroku git repo `stark-temple-39676` was different from the name of the app `gentle-lowlands-46404`. Apparently, the heroku repo name `stark-temple-39676` was for a previous app that I had earlier deployed to Heroku using another Heroku account.

All I had to do was to remove the heroku repo name:

```
git remote rm heroku
```

And then delete the app;

```
heroku apps:destroy --app=gentle-lowlands-46404
```

And then recreate the app:

```
heroku create
```

This time when I pushed the app using the command:

```
git push heroku main
```

it worked perfectly.

**Note**:

1. You can just modify the repo name for the old app to say `heroku-old` if you still need it and then recreate the new app.
2. You can also add the git repo URL for the new app from your Heroku account dashboard instead of deleting it and recreating it.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**