# Can't push to Heroku using git push heroku master (Could not read from remote repository)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, github, ssh

I am trying to push my rails app to Heroku. When I attempt to push to heroku:

```
git push heroku master
```

I get the following error:

```
! Your account abc@abc.com does not have access to APPNAME
! SSH Key Fingerprint: 8b:ac:.......

fatal: Could not read from remote repository
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

When I type:

```
heroku keys
```

I can see my `ssh-rsa` key.

What I have tried:

- Clear all SSH keys (both heroku and gitHub). Create a new SSH key for GitHub and upload this same SSH key to both Heroku and Github
- Opened GitBash and

  ssh-add

  ssh-add -l

To add and verify only one key:

- Login to heroku website and verify only one key at SSH key field

I can push to GitHub fine but not to Heroku. Can anyone please help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Your account someoneelse@gmail.com does not have access to <app-name>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586992/your-account-someoneelsegmail-com-does-not-have-access-to-app-name)

Answer (score 0):

1) Firstly do the heroku keys:add and then try or copy your ssh key and paste it, on the account settings of heroku.

2) Secondly checking that ur this ssh key not be accessed by another heroku app ?