# Heroku: account does not have access to app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm trying to `git pull heroku master`, but I'm getting

```
 !  Your account email@gmail.com does not have access to app_name.
 !  
 !  SSH Key Fingerprint: 30:02:49:32...

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have done `heroku login` and been authenticated successfully. I need to switch account's but not sure what else I need to do besides `heroku login`.

Comment: have you added your ssh keys?

Answer (score 12):

Try all of the helpful answers found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586992/your-account-someoneelsegmail-com-does-not-have-access-to-app-name).

For me, I had two different heroku accounts, each associated with a different git repository. So I had to tell heroku to use specific SSH key for each one (apparently, not just the first available one, which seems to be the default behavior). The exact method that worked for me was following the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9149518/4294745) and then [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13518981/4294745).

The details:

**Create a new rsa key:** Specify any email you want and choose a name that will be easy for you to remember and associate with the specific heroku app. Or you could name it something like /id_rsa_herokualt.

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "youremail[at]domain.com" -f  ~/.ssh/id_rsa_myherokuapp
```

**Add to your machine:** Make sure to type in the exact file name as you just specified it in the last step.

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_myherokuapp
```

**Add to Heroku:** This assumes you have already logged into heroku using `heroku login`.

```
$ heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_myherokuapp.pub
```

**Add an alternate host for heroku.com to your ~/.ssh/config.** Locate this file by going to Finder and pressing command + shift + g and typing in ~/.ssh/. Open the Config file in a text editor, add the following text, and then save it:

```
Host heroku-alt
HostName heroku.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_myherokuapp
```

**Update the .git/config in your project to use the host alias.** Locate this file by going to Finder and pressing command + shift + g and typing in ~/path/to/your/repository/.git. Open the Config file in a text editor, add the following text, and then save it:

```
[remote "heroku"]
  url = git@heroku-alt:myherokuapp.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

**Explanation:** By choosing between heroku and heroku-alt in the remote of the .git/config files of specific projects you can manage which projects use which credentials.

Answer (score 0):

The email you use in Heroku login has to match one of the specified in the Access tab inside your heroku app (in the heroku website).

Also try to change your git email (git config --local user.email "email@email.org") to match the one you use in heroku login.