# Rails app deployment on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I have two heroku accounts one using email abc@gmail.com and one using xyz@gmail.com

previously I deployed a rails app to my xyz@gmail.com account but now I want to deploy to abc@gmail.com account using the same machine. I logged in using my credentials for abc@gmail.com using the following command

```
heroku login
```

but when I do a git push it still uses xyz@gmail.com and gives the error message that xyz@gmail.com does not have access to the application's repository.

I have generated the ssh key for account abc@gmail.com and added it to heroku as well so technically it should work but it is not

please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663103/multiple-heroku-accounts check that

Comment: http://martyhaught.com/articles/2010/12/14/managing-multiple-heroku-accounts/

Answer (score 0):

Heroku login is only used for interaction with the CLI - git uses SSH.

You can either:

Add xyz@gmail.com as a collaborator to abc@gmail.com

or

Assuming that abc@gmail.com already has a public/private key uploaded to Heroku edit/Create ~/.ssh/config

```
Host heroku.abc
    HostName heroku.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<abc.key>
```

Update your projects ~/.git/config to use git@heroku.abc:.... in the remote entries.

So that `git remote -v` shows:

heroku  git@heroku.abc:appname.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.abc:appname.git (push)

So now when you push to the heroku remote SSH will use the key defined on the heroku.abc entry in your ~/.ssh/config